How do use multiple imputation only for intermittent missing values?
I have a dataset with time-ordered variables where I distinguish between a continuous series of missing values including the final value (monotone missing) and missing values where at least one non-missing value separates them from the final value (intermittent missing).
I would like to use multiple imputation to get several versions of a dataset where the intermittent missing values are imputed, but the monotone missing values remain missing (to be imputed later with a slightly different strategy).
Here I have a dataframe with a bunch of missing values as well as a mask that specifies the intermittent values I would like to impute. In this, only the second line with an intermittent missing value and no monotone missing values gets imputed.
library(dplyr)
library(mice)

set.seed(2024)

df <- tribble(
  ~v1,  ~v2,  ~v3,  ~v4,  ~v5,
  5,    NA,   3,    9,    NA,
  6,    6,    NA,   1,    1,
  2,    NA,   2,    NA,   NA,
  4,    8,    7,    NA,   NA,
  7,    4,    2,    5,    4
)

mask <- tribble(
  ~v1,      ~v2,    ~v3,      ~v4,      ~v5,
  FALSE,    TRUE,   FALSE,    FALSE,    FALSE,
  FALSE,    FALSE,  TRUE,     FALSE,    FALSE,
  FALSE,    TRUE,   FALSE,    FALSE,    FALSE,
  FALSE,    FALSE,  FALSE,    FALSE,    FALSE,
  FALSE,    FALSE,  FALSE,    FALSE,    FALSE
)

mi <- mice(data = df,
           where = mask)

complete(mi, action = "long")


What I get is
   .imp .id v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
1     1   1  5 NA  3  9 NA
2     1   2  6  6  3  1  1
3     1   3  2 NA  2 NA NA
4     1   4  4  8  7 NA NA
5     1   5  7  4  2  5  4
6     2   1  5 NA  3  9 NA
7     2   2  6  6  3  1  1
8     2   3  2 NA  2 NA NA
9     2   4  4  8  7 NA NA
10    2   5  7  4  2  5  4

But I want the intermittent values to be non-missing, so something like
   .imp .id v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
1     1   1  5  2  3  9 NA
2     1   2  6  6  3  1  1
3     1   3  2  4  2 NA NA
4     1   4  4  8  7 NA NA
5     1   5  7  4  2  5  4
6     2   1  5  5  3  9 NA
7     2   2  6  6  3  1  1
8     2   3  2  7  2 NA NA
9     2   4  4  8  7 NA NA
10    2   5  7  4  2  5  4


Looks like a bug, why gets v3[2] imputed and v1, v2 not?

@jay.sf I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but my googling indicated that the above is the intended behavior for mice. In short, it's unable to impute V2[1] because that quantity is dependent on v5[1] which I tell it not to impute using the mask.
